# Error: Class must be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php

I have a class that implements several abstract methods. When I extend that class I get the following fatal error message:

```
Class CI_Controller_Rest contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
```

The class with abstract methods:

```
class CI_Controller_Rest extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    abstract public function index();

    abstract public function get();

    abstract public function head();

    abstract public function post();

    abstract public function put();

    abstract public function delete();
}
```

The class where I extend `CI_Controller_Rest`:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller_Rest {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {}

    public function get() {}

    public function head() {}

    public function post() {}

    public function put() {}

    public function delete() {}
}
```

What should I do more than this?

Comment: The error tell you the soution ! No much to add...you must declare that class (CI_Controller_Rest) as abstract, otherwise you must provide implementation for that methods...

Comment: @obe6 oh right! How did I miss that? I thought I changed CI_Controller_Rest to abstract. Right!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If a class has one or more abstract functions, [it MUST be declared as an abstract class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php):

```
abstract class CI_Controller_Rest extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    abstract public function index();

    abstract public function get();

    abstract public function head();

    abstract public function post();

    abstract public function put();

    abstract public function delete();
}
```

Comment: Eh, you were faster by 10 sec :)

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class CI_Controller_Rest extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    abstract public function index();

    abstract public function get();

    abstract public function head();

    abstract public function post();

    abstract public function put();

    abstract public function delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CI_Controller_Rest must be an abstract class because it contains abstract methods

```
abstract class CI_Controller_Rest extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    abstract public function index();

    abstract public function get();

    abstract public function head();

    abstract public function post();

    abstract public function put();

    abstract public function delete();
}
```